# Parsing, formatting and generating data based on input

Tags: php, machine-learning, nlp, text-mining

For some known inputs I have some known outputs/results. Based on this I want the program to generate result based on the input as per pre-filled input-results data.

Example input:

> Enjoy your tea in the morning then have some bread in the lunch. Enjoy the taste of a garlic chicken in the dinner.
> Your day starts with cold coffee. In the noon have some rice and fish curry.

Example output:

> Have tea in the morning. Have some bread in the lunch. Have garlic chicken in the dinner.
> Have cold coffee. Have some rice and fish curry.

I don't want to use `string replace` or `regexp` as it will break often. How or where do I start ?

Comment: PHP is not the best language to do machine learning. There's [PHP-ML](https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but I would look at connecting to AWS or GCP to do this kind of processing if you don't want to use PHP functions. I know AWS has an [SDK for PHP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/), but I haven't personally used it.

Comment: This is definitely an interesting topic, but as worded here, it's too open-ended to fit well in the strict Q&A format of this site. Please note that asking for recommendations of libraries or third-party resources is considered "off-topic" on this site, as explained in the [help].

Answer (score 2):

If you have a large number of input and output pairs, you can treat this as a [sequence to sequence](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html) task. The input can be considered your source and output can be considered as a target. You can easily develop a baseline model using [OpenNMT](https://github.com/OpenNMT/OpenNMT-py).

Answer (score 1):

Not really clear on your how to approach your specific problem, but let me go about a few ways to solve text related issues, since it seems to be what you are interested at.

## Level 0 Static text hashing

IF, and that's a big if, your input is static, you could have digests maping inputs to outputs. But, as you mentioned, this is easily breakable. Even one extra space would result in a mismatch and that's why it's level 0.

## Level 1 Pre-process your input:

Remove all extra spaces before, after and in-between words.

Remove stopwords from your input:

List of common stop-words https://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/common-english-words.txt

This step would transform your input to:

```
Enjoy tea morning bread lunch. Enjoy taste garlic chicken dinner.
day starts cold coffee. noon rice fish curry.
```

Next you could remove verbal conjugation, which doesn't apply to your example, but let's assume you had a sentences like:

```
drink tea, drank juice and drinks soda.
```

This sentence your become:

```
drink tea, drink juice drink soda
```

You could go even deeper and have synonyms normalization, example:

```
drink tea, sip water, slurped a juice, swallow beer
```

Then, all of them would become:

```
drink tea, drink water, drink juice, drink beer
```

After these steps are done, you have kind of a non statistical way of processing text. It all comes down to removing any redundancy and language flourish and getting down to the literal stuff.

And, of course, this approach loses a ton of the value contained in the english language. You can't tell sarcasm, you can't have analogies. So, this works for some domains, but it's not that advanced.
This approach is more about text processing and not language processing. See the difference?

If you need a smarter way to go about this, you should look into full text search algorithms

## Level 2 Full text search algorithms

There are several ways to do this, here is one.
You've got a sentence like:

```
I want pizza
```

This search term would become

```
want piz za
```

And would search for

```
want piz
piz za
want za
```

This is super basic stuff, and it's just to show you how raw text processing works and ways you could go about this. Maybe you could have your inputs processed by level 1 to make them simpler and less variable and then have them processed by level 2 to be indexed  in a db and then you have a nice way to query them

## Level 3 NLP - Natural Language Processing

This is still not machine learning, but it is smarter and it's built on top of all the other steps. basically you would clean your inputs of nonsense and try to apply english gramatical structure to it.

To know more: https://dev.to/nicfoxds/getting-started-in-nlp-b0e

## level 4 Deep learning stuff

Basically, google.
You get a bunch of text, a bunch of search queries, a bunch of user tracking data mapping queries to text. You feed all of that into a neural network and statistical models will detect patterns for you and make your search better as it goes.

## Summary

If this is a project are serious about, look into NLU. It will give you a decent outcome as you track usage. Then, when you have enough user data, go for the deep learning stuff.
There's no easy way around this, you either do this by hand or implement a database that has some of those features, like elasticsearch. But as one of the comments mentioned, php is not a language for this.

Answer (score -1):

If your input is truly known, then you can use `str_replace()` e.g.

```php
$input = 'Enjoy your tea in the morning then have some bread in the lunch. Enjoy the taste of a garlic chicken in the dinner.
Your day starts with cold coffee. In the noon have some rice and fish curry.';
$old = array('Enjoy your ', ' then have ', '. Enjoy the taste of a ', 'Your day starts with ', '. In the noon have ');
$new = array('Have '      , '. Have '    , '. Enjoy '               , 'Have '                , '. Have '            );
$output = str_replace($old, $new, $input);
```

Beware of case sensitivity and things like spaces, periods and other punctuation.

If your input is less known, then you could use regex as you surmised.